# Catch SyntaxError exceptions when inserting script tags into DOM

Tags: javascript, exception, dom, syntax-error

In a single page web application, sometimes new chunks of javascript need to be appended to the page.

Let's say we have the following script tag contents, which do have a syntax error, a missing quote for example. It must be an error which provokes an exception at parse time and not runtime.

```
var test = {"foo":1, "bar":"test, "baz":"foobar"};
```

Now, you create a new script element, inject the text inside and append it to the DOM :

```
var text = 'var test = {"foo":1, "bar":"test, "baz":"foobar"};';        
var node = document.createElement('script');
node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
head.appendChild(node);
```

Of course, at the last line, a "SyntaxError" exception is thrown.

The problem is that putting the last line in a try catch block does not work, the exception is never caught. I managed to capture the error using the old dirty window.onerror thing, but only on Chrome. On IE11 for example, if script errors are disabled, it only works with the console open.

So the question is, how to reliably capture this exception to be able to present a message to the user ?

Thanks

Comment: _“The problem is that putting the last line in a try catch block does not work, the exception is never caught”_ – of course not, because that is not the line that is causing the error (there is no exception to throw here) – appending the script node to the head element has worked _splendidly_ well, nothing went wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

In order to catch the SyntaxError you can use `window.addEventListener('error', ...)` method and prevent the default. Some example code:

```
var sourceCode = ...;

await new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{               

            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'module';
            script.innerHTML = sourceCode + '\n' + 
                               'if(window.scriptLoadedHook){window.scriptLoadedHook();}';               


            var windowErrorHandler = (event) =>{
                event.preventDefault();
                var error = event.error;
                error.stack = error.stack + '\n\n' + sourceCode;                    
                window.removeEventListener('error', windowErrorHandler);
                reject(error);
            };

            window.addEventListener('error', windowErrorHandler);  

            var rejectHandler = (error) =>{
                window.removeEventListener('error', windowErrorHandler);
                reject(error);                  
            };              

            script.addEventListener('error', rejectHandler);
            //script.onerror = rejectHandler;

            script.addEventListener('abort', rejectHandler);
            //script.onabort = rejectHandler;
                         

            var loadedHandler = ()=>{
                window.removeEventListener('error', windowErrorHandler);
                resolve();
            };

            script.addEventListener('load', loadedHandler);
            script.onload = loadedHandler;

            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            try {
                body.appendChild(script); 
            } catch(error){
                reject(error);
            }               

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.warn('Could not process JavaScript code:\n', error);
        })
        .then(()=>{
            //refresh app etc.;
        });                 
        
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a way to catch it, but if you have control over the script that is loaded you can certainly know when any error occurred using the following workaround.

Problem is that SyntaxError doesn't go through "onerror", but instead completes with "onload".
So the hack is to insert a little flag/assignment statement at the end of your source script and check the flag during "onload" callback, in addition to capturing other errors with "onerror".